# Embed power point presentation on my page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

In my case,on the client side the user can select (img(jpg|png|gif") file,pdf file,ppt file) and the data is getting stored in the database.Now in admin pannel i have to show this selected files.what i have done is I am using a if condition
if file is img than i am using img tag (src =folder containg file /database value ) and for pdf i am using anchor tag  hyperlink (href = folder containg file /database value) both are working fine but the problem is with ppt file i did the same as i did for pdf but it is directly downloading the file and i want to show the file only.
I don't know how to this i searched for the plugin also , i am not getting anything.
I tried to use the iframe and (src =folder containg file /database value )
This is also not working its directly downloading the file

Comment: Please visit http://stackoverflow.com/help

Comment: Welcome to the site Ashok. Please read the guidelines on asking questions to get more answers. Your question is currently very difficult to read or make sens of, and is therefore being downvoted. If you take the time to write good (= clear, concise) questions, more people will answer.

Comment: ok , Thanks for the suggestion. I will go throgh the guidelines on asking questions

Comment: Hi Ashok, is my answer what you were looking for ? if yes pls mark as solved and fell free to upvote^^

Comment: Yes ,Now I am implementing the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use Google Doc viewer for that. It handles all kind of files : jpg, gif, png, doc, docx, xls, xlsx, ppt, pptx, etc...

Download and include jQuery in your scripts: 
    `<script type="text/javascript" src="./js/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>`

Create an empty container for your preview :
    `<div id='previewContainer'></div>`

You can display it on clicking on a button for ex :
    `<button class="fileClic" data-file="THE_URL_OF_YOUR_DOC">Display</button>`
Then a little script to embed the google document iframe :

```
$('.fileClic').on('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

var file = $(this).data('file'); // the url of the file you want to preview

$('#previewContainer').html('<iframe src="http://docs.google.com/viewer?url='+file+'&#038;embedded=true" width="400" height="400" style="border: none;"></iframe>') 
});
```

Comment: Vincent it's not working it shows no preview available

Comment: Because in file variable the location of the file is getting stored like http://localhost/folder_name/assets/folder_name/filename

Comment: It's working now.the problem was i was execulting the code on the localhost

Comment: ok cool :) glad that I helped you (don't forget to upvote and mark the answer that solved the issue)